# @media not Overriding in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, overriding, media, responsive

So I've been working on my website and I noticed on the Google Pixel phones my home screen has some cutoff words. So I decided to try and hide them completely unless the screen size is big enough for them to be seen entirely. Here's my webpage for reference, and here's my rule that should be affecting the website.

http://manypoint.org/

```css
   /*
----Fix for Title Screen on Pixel----
    */
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 615px) {
.nivo-caption {
 bottom:25% !important;
}
}
```

Here's a screenshot of what it's doing on that certain devices screen size too.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KuE0.png)

So if you go to the page and inspect that box, you can see that the media rule I have posted above already exists in responsive.css. If you edit it and turn bottom: 10% to bottom: 25% you will see my problem is solved. The only issue, it's not being solved. I am adding this CSS to custom.css which is the last style loaded, and I put it at the bottom of custom.css too. It still hasn't worked. It always uses the original style from responsive.css. Also you can see even with the !important tag it does nothing.

Now I know what you're thinking, just edit responsive.css. Easy fix I know, but I don't have access to that file. It also shouldn't have to come to that, I should be able to override styles in my custom.css since it's loaded last right? Please tell me I'm wrong somewhere in here so I can solve this issue!

Comment: Can you certify that the min and max widths fall within the Google pixel size? It is possible that screen density is fooling your @media rule.

Comment: It probably is, but still the issue stands that I can't edit this class when the screen is that size. I'm just using google chrome inspect tools to drag the screen size back and forth.

Comment: Using Chrome developer tools you should be able to see if your style is being overridden elsewhere. You could try to increase the specificity of your selector.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that specifically, I already have looked through and found that it shouldn't be overridden but it is. How would I increase the specificity? I'm not sure how it would be different, I'm already choosing the class file directly.

Comment: Please see [this resource](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) on CSS specificity. An example: `div .foo {color:red}` is more specific than `.foo {color:blue}`. You could inspect the DOM structure of your page to see if you can apply a more specific selector than `.nivo-caption{}` like `.foo .bar .nivo-caption{}`

Answer (score 0):

I just tried something, and it worked. As above in the comments I was suggested to increase specificity. Then it kind of hit me, maybe I should just try using different width parameters.

That did the trick! Instead of trying to directly override the @media rule that's already somewhere else, I just added a slightly different one. I just changed the pixel counts to 480px and 616px and viola!

Not sure if this is regular behavior, but it solves my problem for sure.

Comment: I believe this bug might have to do with retina displays. It may well not, but here's a link you might find interesting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/-webkit-device-pixel-ratio retina displays show 2px in the space of one to create a higher resolution in smaller spaces.